# Get all string after specific value in php

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, preg-match

I need the desired output whether it's in preg_match or explode that is not an probs.. I need ouput in given array format.

I'm trying to split the string from this variable

**INPUT**

Hi FF_nm,
    Your city is  FF_city and your gender is FF_gender. webinar title is FF_extraparam1
    Again your name is FF_nickname

**OUTPUT**

> array => [nickname,city,gender,extraparam1,nickname]

**Code**

```
<?php
    $data = "Hi FF_nm,
Your city is  FF_city and your gender is FF_gender. webinar title is FF_extraparam1
Again your name is FF_nickname";

    if (($pos = strpos($data, "FIELDMERGE_")) !== FALSE) { 
        $whatIWant = substr($data, $pos+1); 
    }

    echo $whatIWant; 

    ?>
```

Comment: What's the question? Whats the `preg_*` usage you are trying or want?

Comment: I need the desired output whether its in preg_match or explode that is not an probs.. I need ouput in given array format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `explode` with `foreach` loop as:

```
$arr = explode("FIELDMERGE_", $data);
array_shift($arr); // you don't need the first element
foreach($arr as $e) {
    $word = array_shift(explode(" ", $e)); //take the first word
    $res[] = preg_replace('/[^a-z\d]/i', '', $word); //remove the , / . / \n and so on...
}
```

Reference: [array-shift](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php), [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [preg-replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Live example: https://3v4l.org/Oa1sn

Comment: I'm getting the output like `Array ( [0] => nicknameYour [1] => city [2] => gender [3] => extraparamAgain [4] => nickname )`

Comment: I need output like `Array ( [0] => nickname[1] => city [2] => gender [3] => extraparam1 [4] => nickname )`

Comment: @QuestionUser Added `\d` to the regex - hope it fine now. Added also live example in https://3v4l.org/Oa1sn

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match_all` with a positive lookbehind pattern.

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=FF_)\w+/', $data, $fields);
$output = $fields[0];
```